# Dagger return type with async call

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am trying to return a specified type when using a 3rd party function that utilises a callback.  I have an interface

```
public interface AuthenticationService {
    AuthResult signInEmailPassword(String username, String password, AuthListener listener);
}
```

When implementing the interface I am calling an AWS Cognito asynchronous function that uses a callback.

```
public class AwsCognitoAuthenticator implements AuthenticationService {
    @Override
    public AuthResult signUp(String givenName, String username, String password, final AuthListener listener) {
        userPool.signUpInBackground(username, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
    --> return result from signupCallback;
    }
}
```

How can I still return the type of AuthResult when calling this method (signUpInBackground)?  (I don't want to change it to void so that I can use dagger on the interface).

**Edit**

I have tried many different ways in dagger but have been unsuccessful with my attempts.  I am trying to inject the below interface into an activity as a field.

```
@Component(modules = LoginModule.class)
public interface AuthenticationService {
    void signUp(String givenName, String username, String password, AuthListener listener);
    void signInEmailPassword(String username, String password, AuthListener listener);
    void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword);
    void resetPassword();
    void signOut();
}
```

Module

```
@Module
public class LoginModule {
    @Provides
    AuthenticationService provideAuthService() {
        return new AwsCognitoAuthenticator();
    }
}
```

I then get errors for the three declarations that have parameters in the interface saying

> error: This method isn't a valid provision method, members injection
>   method or subcomponent factory method. Dagger cannot implement this
>   method

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: How does changing the type to `void` interfere with using Dagger on the interface? You're fundamentally trying to return a synchronous result from an asynchronous function; can you change the type to `Future<AuthResult>` or `CompletableFuture<AuthResult>`? Of course, if you use Guava, you can use `ListenableFuture<AuthResult>`, which [has some advantages of encapsulation over CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744943/listenablefuture-vs-completablefuture).

Comment: When I use @Provides on a void method, I get "@Provides methods must return a value...".  I basically want to inject AuthenticationService into an Android Activity.

Comment: Are you able to help in any way please @JeffBowman?  I'm completely stuck on how I'd use dagger to inject the above interface into an activity.  I have researched provision/members injection methods and can't see a way to make the interface injectable and testable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be annotating interfaces that you implement with `@Component`. `@Component` means, specifically, the interface that defines your binding graph that you want Dagger to implement for you.

```
@Component(modules = LoginModule.class)
public interface AuthenticationComponent {
  AuthenticationService getAuthenticationService();
}
```

The above code tells Dagger to use the `@Module` classes you list and the `@Inject`-annotated constructors it finds to create the classes you list on the component. Here, that class is AuthenticationService, and per your LoginModule you'll get a concrete AwsCognitoAuthenticator. Dagger generates this implementation adjacent to AuthenticationComponent, such that you can call `create` to get a factory for your fully-created AuthenticationService:

```
AuthenticationComponent authComponent = DaggerAuthenticationComponent.create();
```

Because you have one binding and all it does is call a single constructor manually, you're not going to get a lot of benefit from Dagger here. However, if your graph grows over time, or if you change AwsCognitoAuthenticator to require other dependencies, this could easily pull its weight.

---

Now that Dagger is not involved in your AuthenticationService interface design, you can focus on making a clean API. First and foremost you'll need to decide whether AuthenticationService behaves synchronously or asynchronously. If you're returning AuthResult, you're going to need to create it, so you seem to want synchronous behavior. That said, since you accept AuthListener you seem to be prepared for asynchronous behavior. As a consumer of your API, I wouldn't understand this. Try one of the following instead:

- Accept AuthListener for each of your methods and use that to call back. Then you can return `void`. Presumably the AuthListener you accept has a method that can accept AuthResult whenever the background task completes and you know the result. Most of your methods will return `void`, because there's usually no AuthResult to return synchronously.
- Return a `ListenableFuture<AuthResult>` instead of an AuthResult. This means that the return value of the API is an object that can accept listeners to be called when AuthResult is ready, so you don't need to accept an AuthListener as a parameter anymore. This is slightly more expensive because ListenableFuture needs the data structures to accept an arbitrary number of listeners, but it may compose better (if, say, you need to listen to several ListenableFuture instances all at once).
- Double-down on a synchronous API, such that your AuthenticationService methods don't return until the background task is done. This is a bad idea in most cases, but it's possible, and then you could be sure you have an AuthResult immediately when you need to return.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :).  I had changed from the return type to the callback to using asynchronous methods so makes sense.  I wasn't sure whether the component was meant to be the actual interface or another interface like you say.