# Refactor a ListenableFuture (with onSuccess/onFailure) into a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Because of an upgrade in the Kafka library, I need to rewrite the following code with `ListenableFuture` into one that uses `CompletableFuture`. The difference is briefly explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250452/1005607).

The object being handled is called `SendResult<String,Object>`.

The legacy code is

```
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = ...;
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Object>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final SendResult<String, Object> result) {

                ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = result.getProducerRecord();
                CaseStatusRequest data = (CaseStatusRequest) record.value();

                logger.info("Producing request succeeded: {}", data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
                logger.error("Producing request failed: {}", request.getReceiptNumber());
            }
        });
```

My understanding is, the analogue of `ListenableFuture.onSuccess` is `CompletableFuture.whenComplete`. That refactoring was straightforward. But the `ListenableFuture.onFailure` doesn't have a clear equivalent. There is `CompletableFuture.exceptionally` which must return something, which shouldn't be done; the error handling should be a void operation.

```
        CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = ...;
        future.whenComplete(new BiConsumer<SendResult<String,Object>,Throwable>() {

            @Override
            public void accept(SendResult<String, Object> result, Throwable u) {
                ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = result.getProducerRecord();
                CaseStatusRequest data = (CaseStatusRequest) record.value();

                logger.info("Producing request succeeded: {}", data);   
            }   
        });
        future.exceptionally(new Function<Throwable, SendResult<String,Object>>() {

            @Override
            public SendResult<String, Object> apply(Throwable arg0) {
                logger.error("Producing request failed: {}", request.getReceiptNumber());
                // Something needs to be returned here.
                // Should I return NULL?
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: This is for a producer? Can you instead use the send function that accepts a callback instead of dealing with a Future?

Comment: Have two if statements in `accept` to check which of `result` and `u` is non-null. I think your current code NPEs on exceptional completion.

Comment: Got it. The documentation also says for `whenComplete()`: " the given action is invoked **with the result (or null if none) and the exception (or null if none)** of this stage as arguments. " -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `whenComplete` function will be invoked for both success and failure cases. The signature of `whenComplete` takes the throwable which denotes that in case of a failure, this function will be called with the exception value.

So you may not require the `exceptionally` method at all.

Something like

```
        future.whenComplete(new BiConsumer<SendResult<String,Object>,Throwable>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(SendResult<String, Object> result, Throwable u) {
            if (u != null) {
                logger.error(....)
            }
            else {
                ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = result.getProducerRecord();
                CaseStatusRequest data = (CaseStatusRequest) record.value();

                logger.info("Producing request succeeded: {}", data);   
           }   
      }
    });
```

**Alternative implementation**

You could leverage Kafka Async send method and have a callback to handle the results. This would require some more refactoring of your older code base.

Something like this

```
    producer.send(producerRecord, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                // executes every time a record is successfully sent or an exception is thrown
                if (e == null) {
                    // the record was successfully sent
                    log.info("Received new metadata. \n" +
                            "Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +
                            "Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +
                            "Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +
                            "Timestamp: " + recordMetadata.timestamp());
                } else {
                    log.error("Error while producing", e);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I believe there should be an `else` there as well, since the two conditions need exclusive code and we're not returning immediately; or we need to `return;` immediately.

Comment: Yes, I added the else. Thank you for pointing the issue.