# Replacing ListenableFuture with CompletableFuture in Kafka producer/consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm migrating to `spring-kafka` 3.1. One of the things I've noticed was

```
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(message);

    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Object> result) {
            log.info("Sent message=[" + payload +
                    "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata()
                    .offset() + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            log.info("Unable to send message=["
                    + message + "] due to : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
    return future.get()
            .getRecordMetadata()
            .partition() + "-" + future.get()
            .getRecordMetadata()
            .offset();
```

`ListenableFuture` was deprecated in Spring 6, replaced with `CompletableFuture`. However, there's no `addCallBack` method with `CompletableFuture`. What would be the correct way to fix the above callback, in order to be backwards compatible?

Comment: You can be called back on the CompletableFuture via the method .handleAsync(), which takes a BiFunction where the first parameter is the result (null in case of failure) and the second parameter is a throwable (null in case of success).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ could you please post your answer? Conversely, this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744943/listenablefuture-vs-completablefuture gives a good picture, but not good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Biboo's way better, but why not do the mapping to the desired result in the success step. No need for using the `async` versions of the methods either since you ultimately join anyway (and from what I can tell, this will still be executed in the Thread used by the future, so it's still async to the main Thread.).

```
CompletableFuture<String> mapped = future
  .thenApply(result -> { 
    // or future.thenApply(SendResult::getMetadata).thenApply(metadata ->...
    var metadata = result.getRecordMetadata(); 
    var partition = metadata.getPartition();
    var offset = metadata.offset();
    //log success
    log.info("Sent message=[{}] with offset=[{}]", payload, offset);
    return String.format("%d-%d", partition, offset);

  }).exceptionally(err -> { 
    //log error - shouldn't this be "payload" instead of "message"?
    log.info("Unable to send message=[{}] due to : {}", message, err.getMessage());
    return null;
  });
// sync up
return mapped.get();
```

Note that this will *not* throw an exception as your version does due to your failing `future.get()` in the `return` line, but will return `null` to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Stating in advance that I don't know Kafka, assuming that you have this:

```
CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

... then you should be able to add your callbacks as following:

```
future.handleAsync((result, ex) -> {
    if (result != null) {
        //success
        log.info("Sent message=[" + payload +
            "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata().offset() + "]");
    } else if (ex != null) {
        //failure
        log.info("Unable to send message=[" +
            message + "] due to : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return //whatever you want to return to complete your future (or throw to complete exceptionally)
});
```

This is the JavaDoc of the method in JDK 11 if you want more details (shouldn't be different in other JDKs but I suggest you to check yours anyway):

```
 /**
 * Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes
 * either normally or exceptionally, is executed using this stage's
 * default asynchronous execution facility, with this stage's
 * result and exception as arguments to the supplied function.
 *
 * <p>When this stage is complete, the given function is invoked
 * with the result (or {@code null} if none) and the exception (or
 * {@code null} if none) of this stage as arguments, and the
 * function's result is used to complete the returned stage.
 *
 * @param fn the function to use to compute the value of the
 * returned CompletionStage
 * @param <U> the function's return type
 * @return the new CompletionStage
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `thenAcceptAsync(Consumer<? super T> action)` if you do not like to perform the null checks inside whenCompleteAsync or handleAsync. You can also add on exceptionallyAsync() to handle exceptions. It should look something like:

```
future.thenAcceptAsync(result -> { 
    //log success
    log.info("Sent message=[" + payload +
                "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata()
                .offset() + "]");
}).exceptionallyAsync(err -> { 
    //log error;
    log.info("Unable to send message=[" +
        message + "] due to : " + err.getMessage());
    return null; //this usually lets you handle exceptions - like providing a value in case or errors - so you can continue the chain, but in this case, nothing doing so...
});
return future.get()...
```

I like this better since I can properly separate success and failure code. Though, exceptionallyAsync is only available java 12 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you would have encountered this issue during upgrading your existing spring boot application from 2.x.x to 3.x.x

As you can see in the versions spring-kafka versions on the github the ListenableFuture is changed to CompletableFuture.

Spring Kafka Template after 3.x.x see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/3.0.x/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.java)
Spring Kafka Template before 3.x.x see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2.9.x/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.java)

We can clearly see that the ListenableFuture is changed to CompletableFuture. Hence, we need to migrate to CompletableFuture.

So, follow the below steps to migrate to CompletableFuture

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

Change the ListenableFuture to CompletableFuture from the above to the one mentioned below

```
CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

Move the logic of onSuccess method to else block and onFailure to if (throwable != null) block respectively.

```
future.whenComplete((result, throwable) -> {
       if (throwable != null) {
            // handle failure
            log.info("Unable to send message=["
                + message + "] due to : " + throwable.getMessage());
       } else {
            // handle success
            log.info("Sent message=[" + message +
                "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata()
                        .offset() + "]");
       }
    });
```

The completeable future whenComplete method accepts a BiConsumer which accepts the org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<K,V> in the above example as the first parameter and java.lang.Throwable as its second parameter. You can go through the official documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

There would be no changes to your return statement, that would remain as it is.